# Почему указатель равен NULL?

Tags: c++

Видимо ответ крайне прост, но...

Есть файлы 1.cpp и 2.cpp, в файле 1.cpp:

```
void Fun(){  
  double *Arr;  
  Arr=NULL;  
  GetTable(Arr);   
}
```

в файле 2.cpp:

```
double * GlobalTable=new double[10];  
void GetTable(double * Table){  
Table=new double[10];  
    CopyMemory(Table,GlobalTable,10*sizeof(double));  
}
```

В итоге вызова ф-ции GetTable(), указатель Arr всё равно равен NULL! ПОЧЕМУ!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Передавать надо не указатель, а указатель-на-указатель.

```
void Fun()
{  
  double *Arr;  
  Arr=NULL;  
  GetTable(&Arr);   
}

double * GlobalTable=new double[10];  
void GetTable(double ** Table)
{  
    *Table=new double[10];  
    CopyMemory(*Table,GlobalTable,10*sizeof(double));  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void GetTable(double *& Table)
{  
    Table=new double[10];  
    CopyMemory(Table,GlobalTable,10*sizeof(double));  
}
```

также можно передавать не по значению а по ссылке, указывая **&** в параметре функции

Comment: По-моему, у Вас затесалась лишняя \*. Правильно, я считаю, будет так:
<pre>void GetTable(double \*& Table)</pre>
т.е. передача указателя на double* по ссылке.

Comment: вы правы, подправил, так вроде будет работать

Comment: Мне кажется что (double *& Table) = (double  Table)

Comment: & Table - определяется адрес переменной, затем этот адрес разыминовывается * , то есть получаем Таиду

Comment: Хорошо, тогда обьясните смысл обьявления (double * & Table)

Comment: Первоисточник: 

http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/cpp/cpp-language-straustrup2-page61.html

Comment: Еще раз:
void func (double x); // локальная переменная x, передача по значению<p>
void func (double \*x); // передача по указателю, мы можем изменить значение из ф-ции, но при этом сам x - локален. И мы можем изменить адрес на который он указывает<p>
void func (const double \*x); // передача по указателю. Мы не можем изменить значение. Мешает модификатор const. Удобно для передачи массивов данных C-style. При этом адрес, на который указывает x мы можем изменить<p>
void func (double &x); // передача по ссылке. Опять же можем изменить значение внешней переменной.

Comment: void func (double \*\*x);// передача указателя на указатель. Это если нужно изменить указатель.<p>
void func (double \*&x);// передача указателя по ссылке. Т.е. опять же мы можем изменить значение указателя, т.е. адрес на который он указывает.